# Randomly changing game scenes in unity c#

Tags: unity, c#, random

Is there any way that I can randomly change scenes in Unity C# using arrays?

Comment: it so easy as I can understand your question, could you please add some details what you actually want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for an array, you just need to know total amount of scenes you have:

```
//using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

void LoadRandomScene(int totalSceneAmount)
{
    int random = Random.Range(0, totalSceneAmount-1);
    SceneManager.LoadScene(random, LoadSceneMode.Single);
}
```

***Note:*** You need to add all of your scenes to build in Build Settings window.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want only that then you can do it by this way.

```
string[] scenes = new string[3]{"Gameplay1","Gameplay2","Gameplay3"};

void LoadRandomScene()
{
    string randomSceneName = scenes[Random.Range(0,scenes.Lenght)];
    Application.LoadLevel(randomSceneName);
}
```

Comment: Please note that `Application.LoadLevel` is obsolete now. All Scene loading jobs should be done via `UnityEngine.SceneManagement` class.